# IE9 forcing inline block elements to clear floats

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css-float, css

I have an interesting issue that took me a while to replicate with IE9, but it involves floats AND inline-block elements. Due to the desired flow of content in mobile, I'm trying to get a certain order of elements, using floats and inline blocks. However, they flow together rather strangely. I'll defer to a fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/UEAd5/5/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Float and Inline-Block Lab</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    .green {
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #0ABC00;
    }

    .yellow {
        float: right;
        height: 50px;
        width: 40%;
        background-color: #ABC000;
    }

    .blue {
        float: left;
        width: 65%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #00ABC0;
    }

    .red {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #AB0000;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="green">(A)</div>
    <div class="yellow">(B)</div>
    <div class="blue">(C)</div>
    <div class="red">(D)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox / Chrome and even IE8 (though not jsfiddle) it works fine. Red falls right under Yellow. However, in IE9, when Blue pushes Red to the right, it also forces its y-offset to clear Green with it. Is this standard behavior or a bug in IE9, and are there any workarounds where the order of DIVs can be preserved?

John

Comment: Interesting problem.  It's because D is too tall to fall between B & D and stay next to A.  If you reduce the height of D, you'll see it snuggle right in there, but since it can't fit there it jumps down in IE.  I've tested it in IE 8 (compatible mode), IE 9, and IE 10, and it renders it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for your current method, but you can change your floats to `display:inline-block`, and apply `position:relative; top: -30px` to block D, which renders the same in firefox and IE.  Also, since the divs are now becoming inline-blocks, the whitespace between them becomes important, so I've removed them by applying `font-size:0` to the body, and `font-size: 16px to body > div`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UEAd5/6/
jsfiddle for IE 8: http://jsfiddle.net/UEAd5/6/show/light

Comment: Hi Robert. Unfortunately, that won't work out because the content is different on various pages. It should just fall wherever (B) ends, whether it's above or below the end of (A).

Comment: Sorry then, I'm out of ideas.  You might need to put a bounty on this one to attract the attention of more people.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, for now I'll just be letting IE9 be a little bit strange -- it's luckily only about 10px of difference, so it won't present an issue. I also find it funny that only IE9 renders it this way, IE8 is fine, just like everything else.

Comment: It also does it in IE 10, and in IE 10 when I set it to IE 8 mode as well.  I don't have a real IE 8 to test with anymore, are you sure it does it in IE 8?

Comment: I said IE8 renders it correctly, but IE9 and IE10 render it abnormally